# How to have Footer stay at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, position, footer

I am wondering how I can get the footer to stay at the bottom when there is not enough content.

If I use this for the css`position:absolute;
    bottom:0;`

The problem is if there is more than enough content the footer floats and overlays the content.

http://niceguy.co/

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/  The footer sticks to the bottom of the window unless the content pushes it down past the bottom of the window.

Comment: i tried it but i can't get it to work. I have the following code
'html, body {
height: 100%;
}
.zone-content-wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -4em;

}

.section-footer, .push {
 height: 4em;
}'

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;`

Comment: but the thing is i don't want the footer to be fixed. I just want it to be glued to the bottom of the page.

Thanks.

Comment: did you define the width? after position: absolute

Answer (score 0):

Your structure needs to look something like this:

```
<body>
    <section id="wrap><!-- This has header, etc --></section>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

then CSS (where 50px is the height of your footer, just replace that):

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#wrap {
     min-height: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 50px;
}
footer {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```